# Relating a canvas to a figure wxPython

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, wxpython

I would like to know how to perform the following pseudocode in python when embedding a matplotlib figure inside of a wxPython FigureCanvasWxAgg instance:

the following items need to be used:

- *-*-*-*- IMPORTS THAT CAN BE USED *-*-*-*-

  import wx

  from matplotlib.figure import Figure

  from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas

  -*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-
- main_canvas;
- shadow_canvas;
- big_plot [a matplotlib figure instance with one big plot in it -- like the one you would make with figure.add_subplots(1,1,1)];
- small_subplots [a matplotlib figure instance with, say, 2 subplots in it -- you would make with figure.add_subplots(2,1,i), where 1<=i<=2]
- a function called SwapView(main_canvas,shadow_canvas,big_plot,small_subplots) that essentially swaps the figure that is currently in shadow_canvas with the one in main_canvas (so keep switching between the one with a big plot and the one with many small plots)
- a function UpdateDisplay() that dynamically updates the display every time you call SwapView()

  ```
   ******* PSEUDOCODE *******
   main_canvas.show()
   shadow_canvas.hide()
   main_canvas has big_plot initially
   shadow_canvas has small_subplots initially

   if big_plot in main_canvas:
        SwapView(...) ---> should put big_plot in shadow_canvas and small_subplots in the main_canvas
   else:
        SwapView(...) ---> should put the small_subplots in shadow_canvas and the big_plot in main_canvas
   UpdateDisplay()
   ******* END OF CODE *******
  ```

Here is my initial attempt at this code and unfortunately I can't find a way to find which figure is the one currently displayed.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import wx
import time
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas

class myframe(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent = None, id = -1, title = 'LoadFigure()', size = (800,800))

        self.figurePanel = FigurePanel(parent = self)

        canvas1 = self.figurePanel.canvas
        canvas2 = self.figurePanel.enlarged_canvas

        fig1 = self.figurePanel.enlarged_figure
        fig2 = self.figurePanel.figure

        fig1.set_canvas(canvas1) #enlarged_fig resides in canvas1
        fig2.set_canvas(canvas2) #fig resides in canvas2

        #Show both canvases ---> canvas2 will override canvas1, but when canvas2 hides canvas1 should show
        canvas2.Show()
        canvas1.Show()
        self.Show()
        print "Starting to swap displays!"
        time.sleep(1)
        for i in range(10):
            print "run: %d"%i
            self.SwapView(big_plot = fig1,small_plots = fig2,main_canvas = canvas1,shadow_canvas = canvas2)
            time.sleep(1)

    def SwapView(self,big_plot,small_plots,main_canvas,shadow_canvas):
        '''
            Keep swapping the main_canvas with the shadow_canvas to show either fig1 or fig2.

            Initially, big_plot has main_canvas and small_plots have shadow_canvas
        '''
        wx.Yield()
        print list(main_canvas)
        print list(big_plot.get_children())
        time.sleep(2)
        for child in big_plot.get_children():
            if child == main_canvas:
                print 'big_plot has main_canvas'
                big_plot.set_canvas(shadow_canvas)
                small_plots.set_canvas(main_canvas)
                main_canvas.draw()
                wx.Yield()
                main_canvas.Show()
            else:
                print 'big_plot has shadow_canvas'

        for child in small_plots.get_children():
            if child == main_canvas:
                print 'small_plots has main_canvas'
                small_plots.set_canvas(shadow_canvas)
                big_plot.set_canvas(main_canvas)
                main_canvas.draw()
                wx.Yield()
                main_canvas.Show()
            else:
                print 'small_plots has shadow_canvas'

class FigurePanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.figPanel = self
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.figure = Figure(figsize = (8,6.1), dpi =60)
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        self.ax.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
        self.enlarged_figure = Figure(figsize = (8,6.1), dpi = 60)
        self.ax1 = self.enlarged_figure.add_subplot(2,1,1)
        self.ax2 = self.enlarged_figure.add_subplot(2,1,2)
        self.ax1.plot([1,2,3],[1,4,9])
        self.ax2.plot([1,2,3],[1,4,9])
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.enlarged_canvas = FigureCanvas(self,-1,self.enlarged_figure)
        self.Layout()
        self.Fit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    fr = myframe()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that might need it, here's the solution that I came up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import wx
import time
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas

class myframe(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent = None, id = -1, title = 'SWAP!', size = (480,390))

        self.figurePanel = FigurePanel(parent = self)

        self.canvas1 = self.figurePanel.canvas
        self.canvas2 = self.figurePanel.enlarged_canvas

        self.fig1 = self.figurePanel.enlarged_figure
        self.fig2 = self.figurePanel.figure

        self.fig1.set_canvas(self.canvas1) #enlarged_fig resides in canvas1

        self.canvas1.Show()
        self.Show()

        self.canvas2.mpl_connect("button_release_event",self.OnLoadFigure) #Enable the detection of mouseclicks for the plots in the plotting window
        print "Click anywhere on the figure to swap the plots!"
        self.display = 1

    def OnLoadFigure(self,event = None):
        print "Tried to load figure"
        if event != None:
            self.display = self.SwapView(big_plot = self.fig1 ,small_plots = self.fig2 , display = self.display, main_canvas = self.canvas1 , shadow_canvas = 0)

    def SwapView(self,big_plot = None,display = -1, small_plots = None,main_canvas = None,shadow_canvas = None):
        '''
            Keep swapping the main_canvas with the shadow_canvas to show either fig1 or fig2.

            Initially, big_plot has main_canvas and small_plots have shadow_canvas
        '''
        wx.Yield()
        print display
        if display == 1: #Show the big plot
            print 'big_plot showing'
            big_plot.set_canvas(main_canvas)
            main_canvas.Show()
            time.sleep(0.01) #Fastest time you can pick
            wx.Yield()
        else:
            print 'small_plots showing'
            main_canvas.Hide()
            wx.Yield()

        self.Refresh(canvas = main_canvas)
        display = not(display)
        return display

    def Refresh(self,canvas = None,figure = None):
        wx.Yield()
        if canvas != None:
            print "draw"
            canvas.draw()
        self.Update()
        self.figurePanel.Update()
        wx.Yield()

class FigurePanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.figPanel = self
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.figure = Figure(figsize = (8,6.1), dpi =60)
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        self.ax.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
        self.enlarged_figure = Figure(figsize = (8,6.1), dpi = 60)
        self.ax1 = self.enlarged_figure.add_subplot(2,1,1)
        self.ax2 = self.enlarged_figure.add_subplot(2,1,2)
        self.ax1.plot([1,2,3],[1,4,9])
        self.ax2.plot([1,2,3],[1,4,9])
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.enlarged_canvas = FigureCanvas(self,-1,self.enlarged_figure)
        self.Layout()
        self.Fit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    fr = myframe()
    app.MainLoop()
```

To make the display change, click on the figure.